# Select element by contents using CSS or XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, capybara

How to get link with text "Next" in the code bellow using CSS or XPath?

```
<div id="pagination">
    <a href="link">2</a>
    <a href="link">3</a>
    <a href="link">4</a>
    <a href="link">5</a>
    <a href="link">6</a>
    <a href="link">7</a>
    <a href="link">8</a>
    <a href="link">9</a>
    <a href="link">10</a>
    <a href="link">Next</a>
    <a href="link">Last</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not use jquery or CSS is must?I think using CSS it is not possible.

Comment: It must be CSS or XPath since Capybara supports just them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want. If you want the tenth link:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="pagination">
    <a href="link">2</a>
    <a href="link">3</a>
    <a href="link">4</a>
    <a href="link">5</a>
    <a href="link">6</a>
    <a href="link">7</a>
    <a href="link">8</a>
    <a href="link">9</a>
    <a href="link">10</a>
    <a href="link">Next</a>
    <a href="link">Last</a>
</div>
EOT

doc.search('a')[9]
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80763880 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80763498 name="href" value="link">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80762fd4 "Next">]>
```

Or:

```
doc.at('//a[9]')
```

If you don't know which element number it'll be but are keying off the text and want to use CSS, I'd do:

```
doc.search('a').select{ |n| n.content == 'Next' }.first
```

Unfortunately, CSS can't search the text of a tag, so you have to get a bit creative. XPath can do it:

```
doc.at('//a[text()="Next"]')
```

Comment: I don't know position of a tag since it changes so, 2nd and 3rd solution are good.

Answer (score 1):

```
path = "/a[.='Next']"
```

do query for that path, you will get `a` element with 'Next' as it's `text()`.

Comment: Can you just explain what is meaning of `.` here? Why not `"/a[text()='Next'"`

Comment: Sure you can do that too! `.` basically means `current node` if I am not wrong. I remember `.` from earlier so can't tell for sure now *what* it is.

Answer (score 0):

**If the rule is that the `a` whose string value is `"Next"` is the last-but one child of `div`, just use**:

```
//div[@id='pagination']/a[last()-1]
```

Here we suppose that at most one `div` exists in the XML document whose `id` attribute has the value of `"pagination"` -- this is a fair assumption with XHTML documents.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@id='pagination']/a[last()-1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <a href="link">2</a>
    <a href="link">3</a>
    <a href="link">4</a>
    <a href="link">5</a>
    <a href="link">6</a>
    <a href="link">7</a>
    <a href="link">8</a>
    <a href="link">9</a>
    <a href="link">10</a>
    <a href="link">Next</a>
    <a href="link">Last</a>
</div>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected node from this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<a href="link">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is also possible to do this with css:

```
 #pagination a:nth-last-child(2)
```

assuming it is always the 2nd last, and you can use css 3 selectors